# Database connection test script works but not wp-config.php

Tags: mysql, wordpress, database-connection

I have ran through that boring *"Error establishing a database connection"* error when trying to get a wordpress site I downloaded to run locally. I have downloaded and imported the database, got it running locally. I even got a test script (db-check.php)to check:

```
   <?
    $connect=mysql_connect('localhost', 'admincheck', 'ch3ck') or die("Unable to Connect");
    mysql_select_db("checkers_db") or die("Could not open the db");
    $showtablequery="SHOW TABLES FROM checkers_db";
    $query_result=mysql_query($showtablequery);
    while($showtablerow = mysql_fetch_array($query_result))
    {
    echo $showtablerow[0]." ";
    }
    ?>
```

It lists all the tables fine, but for some reason the wp-config.php just gives me the vague:
**"Error establishing a database connection"** without the slightest clue about what is going on.

```
                <?php
                /**
                 * The base configurations of the WordPress.
                 *
                 * This file has the following configurations: MySQL settings, Table Prefix,
                 * Secret Keys, WordPress Language, and ABSPATH. You can find more information
                 * by visiting {@link http://codex.wordpress.org/Editing_wp-config.php Editing
                 * wp-config.php} Codex page. You can get the MySQL settings from your web host.
                 *
                 * This file is used by the wp-config.php creation script during the
                 * installation. You don't have to use the web site, you can just copy this file
                 * to "wp-config.php" and fill in the values.
                 *
                 * @package WordPress
                 */


                // ** MySQL settings - You can get this info from your web host ** //
                /** The name of the database for WordPress */
                define('DB_NAME', 'checkers_db');


                /** MySQL database username */
                define('DB_USER', 'admincheck');

                /** MySQL database password */
                define('DB_PASSWORD', 'ch3ck');

                /** MySQL hostname */
                define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');

                /** Database Charset to use in creating database tables. */
                define('DB_CHARSET', 'utf8');

                /** The Database Collate type. Don't change this if in doubt. */
                define('DB_COLLATE', '');




                /**#@-*/

                /**
                 * WordPress Database Table prefix.
                 *
                 * You can have multiple installations in one database if you give each a unique
                 * prefix. Only numbers, letters, and underscores please!
                 */
                $table_prefix  = 'wp_';

                /**
                 * WordPress Localized Language, defaults to English.
                 *
                 * Change this to localize WordPress. A corresponding MO file for the chosen
                 * language must be installed to wp-content/languages. For example, install
                 * de_DE.mo to wp-content/languages and set WPLANG to 'de_DE' to enable German
                 * language support.
                 */
                define('WPLANG', '');

                /**
                 * For developers: WordPress debugging mode.
                 *
                 * Change this to true to enable the display of notices during development.
                 * It is strongly recommended that plugin and theme developers use WP_DEBUG
                 * in their development environments.
                 */
                /** debuging mode*/
                define( 'WP_DEBUG', true );
                define( 'SCRIPT_DEBUG', true );

                /* That's all, stop editing! Happy blogging. */

                /** Absolute path to the WordPress directory. */
                if ( !defined('ABSPATH') )
                    define('ABSPATH', dirname(__FILE__) . '/');

                /** Sets up WordPress vars and included files. */
                require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-settings.php');
```

Does anything here stick out as an error? Anything that I am missing or adding unnecessarily?

Answer (score 0):

Have you also modified the parameteres from the wp_options database "siteurl", "home" to match your localhost environment?

Comment: I have checked the database again, for some reason there were a lot of rows missing including database , site URL. I have now imported the database again but it is giving me the following error: `#1062 - Duplicate entry '7' for key 'PRIMARY'` What does this mean?

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer on this [thread](http://www.zen-cart.com/showthread.php?205878-1062-Duplicate-entry-1-for-key-PRIMARY-after-importing-old-database)

So I checked the **Add DROP TABLE / VIEW / PROCEDURE / FUNCTION / EVENT statement** option and re-imported the database.